# jOOQ codegen fails because of "Invalid content" `visibilityModifier` and `includeExcludePackageRoutines`

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq, jooq-codegen

I have a `postgres:13.5-alpine` database running and set up jOOQ like so:

versions

```
plugin_jooq=7.1.1
lib_jooq=3.16.6
```

gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'nu.studer.jooq' version "${plugin_jooq}"
}

dependencies {
    api "org.postgresql:postgresql"

    implementation "org.jooq:jooq:${lib_jooq}"
    implementation "org.jooq:jooq-meta:${lib_jooq}"
    implementation "org.jooq:jooq-codegen:${lib_jooq}"
}

jooq {
    version = "${lib_jooq}"
    edition = nu.studer.gradle.jooq.JooqEdition.OSS

    configurations {
        mydb {
            generateSchemaSourceOnCompilation = true

            generationTool {
                logging = org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Logging.WARN
                jdbc {
                    driver = 'org.postgresql.Driver'
                    url = 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb'
                    user = '<username>'
                    password = '<password>'
                    properties {
                        property {
                            key = 'PAGE_SIZE'
                            value = 2048
                        }
                    }
                }
                generator {
                    name = 'org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGenerator'
                    database {
                        name = 'org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase'
                        inputSchema = 'public'
                        includes = '.*'
                        excludes = ''
                    }
                    target {
                        directory = 'build/generated/sources/'
                        packageName = 'my.app.jooq'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

build.dependsOn generateMydbJooq
```

when I run codegen, I get

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 927; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a:
Invalid content was found starting with element
'{"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":includeExcludePackageRoutines}'.

One of '{
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":properties, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":regexFlags, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":includeTables, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":includeEmbeddables, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":includeRoutines, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":includeTriggerRoutines, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":includePackages, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":includePackageRoutines, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":includePackageUDTs, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":includePackageConstants, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":includeUDTs, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":includeDomains, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":includeSequences, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":includeIndexes, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":includePrimaryKeys, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":includeUniqueKeys, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":includeForeignKeys, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":includeCheckConstraints, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":includeSystemIndexes, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":includeSystemCheckConstraints, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":includeInvisibleColumns, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":recordVersionFields, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":recordTimestampFields, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":syntheticObjects, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":syntheticIdentities, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":syntheticPrimaryKeys, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":overridePrimaryKeys, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":dateAsTimestamp, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":ignoreProcedureReturnValues, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":unsignedTypes, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":integerDisplayWidths, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":inputCatalog, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":outputCatalog, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":outputCatalogToDefault, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":inputSchema, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":outputSchema, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":outputSchemaToDefault, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":catalogs, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":schemata, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":schemaVersionProvider, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":catalogVersionProvider, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":orderProvider, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":embeddables, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":embeddablePrimaryKeys, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":embeddableUniqueKeys, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":embeddableDomains, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":customTypes, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":enumTypes, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":forcedTypes, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":forceIntegerTypesOnZeroScaleDecimals, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":tableValuedFunctions, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":logSlowQueriesAfterSeconds, 
"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":logSlowResultsAfterSeconds
}' is expected.
```

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 3351; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element
'{"http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd":visibilityModifier}'.

One of '{...}' is expected.
```

How do I resolve this?

**UPDATE**

Trying to apply @LukasEder's suggestion. Added the buildscript but error persists. Spun up some dependency tree, and these are the only dependencies mentioning jooq:

```
+--- project :my-app
|    +--- org.jooq:jooq:3.16.6 -> 3.14.15
|    |    +--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.2 -> 1.0.3
|    |    \--- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1
|    |         \--- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:1.2.0

|    +--- org.jooq:jooq-meta:3.16.6 -> 3.14.15
|    |    \--- org.jooq:jooq:3.14.15 (*)
|    \--- org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.16.6 -> 3.14.15
|         +--- org.jooq:jooq:3.14.15 (*)
|         \--- org.jooq:jooq-meta:3.14.15 (*)
```

**UPDATE**

Downgrade to 3.14.15 did not resolve this.

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to solve it somehow?

Comment: @Arsen Somehow, yes, though I hate to say I didn't write down the resolution, at the time. Let me try to sum up our current setup... (1) group "org.jooq" as a dependency is excluded from the spring boot jooq starter, with jooq being its own dependency, (2) the build script workaround mentioned in Lukas' answer is in place, (3) the workaround from https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin/issues/183 is in place, and I think one of those - or maybe the combination of all - may have had the desired effect. Sorry I cannot be of more help. :( Write the answer down, when you find out.

Answer (score 1):

The third party code generation plugin you're using seems to be wired towards an older XSD version for your configuration objects. This can have various reasons, not sure why you're running into this, but as per the documentation here:
https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin#enforcing-the-jooq-configuration-xml-schema-version

You can enforce an XSD version like this:

```
buildscript {
    configurations['classpath'].resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
        if (requested.group == 'org.jooq') {
            useVersion '3.16.6'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ah, wonders of having a multi-project gradle setup... Thank you. Error persists in spite of the added buildscript. I assume you're right and that's going to be the source, it might take a while, though, before I figure out where and how I can apply your suggestion and accept this answer. xD

Comment: @User1291: I figured it might not be the answer to your problem, but it could still be the answer to someone else's problem who stumbles upon this Stack Overflow question...

Comment: I don't suppose the dependency tree (see update) tells you more than it does me? If it's all in the same project, the buildscript should take effect, no?

Comment: @User1291: I'm sorry, I don't know what might be causing those outdated dependencies. Spring Boot, perhaps?

Comment: I've now gotten rid of the downgrade by just letting spring do its thing and choosing that version ... still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update:

```
generateSchemaSourceOnCompilation = false
```